# Textarea CSS issue on "needs moderator attention"

Tags: bug, status-declined, flags, design

To reproduce:

1. Click *Flag* (question or answer)
2. Click *other (needs moderator attention)*

The textarea is too wide:

#### StackOverflow

> [image]

#### AskUbuntu

> [image]

#### StackExchange

> [image]

Most probably affects other sites, but didn't check. I think it's enough. `:-)`

Reproducing on:

- `Chromium Version 40.0.2214.111 Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)`
- `Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.76 (64-bit)`
- `Firefox 36.0`

(I'm using Ubuntu 15.04)

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Firefox 36.0.1.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m

Comment: Whoups, I'm running `Chromium Version 40.0.2214.111 Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)`...

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 37.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: No-repro on *Win 8.1 FF 37.0.1*; No-repro on *Debian 7 Iceweasel 31.1*

Comment: No repro on OSX 10.10 Chrome latest version or Win7 Chrome latest version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue unique to browsers on certain *nix platforms (looks like specific versions of the underlying linked libraries).

The browser, under these conditions doesn't respect the explicit styling but uses the `cols` attribute to render the width.

Since this is out of our control and only effects a small number of users (and is visual only - it doesn't effect functionality), we will not be fixing it.

Comment: FYI [some time ago I reported this same bug on Iceweasel 31.7.0.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257580/broken-layout-for-flagging-for-moderation-attention-textbox) I am now using 38.6.0 (package version 38.6.0esr-1~deb7u1) on Debian Wheezy 7.9, and the problem is gone. The layout looks exactly as it should.