# Broken layout for flagging for moderation attention textbox

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, firefox

The layout of textbox for the `in need of moderator intervention` flags is broken, in that its content overflows it's outer `<div id="popup-flag-post">` container. My browser is Firefox 31.7.0 (technically Iceweasel 31.7.0) on Debian 7.8 Wheezy.

I tried this on both a random Stack Overflow question:

[image: SO Q broken textbox]

as well as a Travel SE answer:

[image: TSE A broken textbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that is specific to FireFox/IceWeasel on **some** linux distributions.

These browsers do not respect the width css properties and seem to render the `cols` property with their own width setting.

We are not fixing this issue, as it effects a very small number of people and is only a visual glitch (i.e. everything else works).

Comment: It is a visual glitch indeed, everything else seems to work fine. For completeness sake, my impression is that this is the first time I encounter this bug, whilst I've been using this browser on SE since my first days on the sites. It might therefore be due to a recent update of Iceweasel on my machine.

Comment: @Oded I get this with chrome on Ubuntu - both major pieces of software... Can this at least be fixed - especially because it affects Ask Ubuntu (lotta people on linux there).

Comment: @Tim - we tried. But different browsers on different distros (or even different versions of the same distro) either respect css width, or interpret the cols property differently. We can't do distro/version/browser detection (and it wouldn't be reliable anyways).

Comment: @Oded okay fair enough. I'm surprised chrome does it but there we go. Thanks for looking into it.